# Link does not work using Boostrap Navigation?

Tags: css

This is my navigation using Boostrap 5

```html
<div class="force-overflow">
    <h1 class="blog-name pt-lg-4 mb-0">
      <a href="https:// site .com/" class="no-text-decoration"> Brand Name </a>
    </h1>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" >

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div id="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" >
```

ETC ETC

However, when in Mobile View, the "Brand Name" is visible but there is no link - which is v odd b/c it is visible in the source code...

Any idea how to problem-solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Seemed to be working properly for me in both a fiddle and a codepen.

Comment: Is it solved, if you fix that space in your URL?

Comment: Maybe on mobile view there is some element that is on top of your button and it becomes not clickable?